# SQL Server Pivot Table Order By Clause Mystery

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot-table

I am making a pivot table with customers down the left side and dates across the top so I can see how much each customer spends every day.  I am totally new to this so with a lot of help from the internet, I assembled some code that works and gives me a pivot table.

The problem is that the dates are in random order.  Wherever I put an order by phrase in, it gives me an error that I have to use Top or Offset in inline functions or views.

How do I get the columns sorted in order?

On a side note, any feedback to improve my code would be much appreciated.  My DL_Daily table has customer number, the date and total sales for that customer for that date.

```
SELECT * INTO #DailyReport
FROM
(SELECT customer,salesdate [DATE], salesamt from DL_Daily where salesdate  
  between '2016/05/01' and '2016/05/31' )  TAB


SELECT * INTO #FileDates
FROM
(      
SELECT distinct salesdate [DATE] from DL_Daily where salesdate between 
    '2016/05/01' and '2016/05/31'  

)   TAB


DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)


SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']', 
           '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM #DailyReport ) PV  


PRINT @cols

--Now pivot it

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
          SELECT * FROM 
         (
             SELECT * FROM #DailyReport 
         ) x
         PIVOT 
         (
             SUM(salesamt)
             FOR [DATE] IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) p      

        '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

DL Daily Sample Data:

```
Customer   Date  Sales
1       5/1/2016   520.75
1       5/2/2016   501.75
2       5/1/2016   15.75
3       5/1/2016   150.75
3       5/2/2016   507.35
3       5/3/2016   530.75
1       5/3/2016   250.75

Results

Customer   5/1      5/3     5/2

1         520.75     250.75     501.75
2          15.25
3         150.75     530.75     507.35
```

Desired Results:  The columns to be in this order 5/1  5/2   5/3

Comment: show sample data, current result and desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Okay - I improved my question.  Do you have any suggestions for my problem?

Comment: Yes, you say you try order by? Show us where you try it, maybe like  a comment code?

Comment: I tried it within every other select statement.  Thanks for your help, Juan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order by` should work. Also try with format `111` instead of `106`

```
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + 
                         ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 111) + ']', 
                         '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 111) + ']')
FROM  (  SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] 
         FROM #DailyReport 
      ) PV  
ORDER BY [DATE]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Juan.  I tried it every other place.  I thought I tried it there but I guess not.   Also, thanks  for the date tip.